# Math to account for winner in RouletteWheel

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

I'm going to be honest with you all. Since high school ended and I've had a year away from school a lot of the math has been faded out. I am creating this roulettewheel for the page I'm doing at the moment and now I have to calculate the winner from where the ball stops.

The ball has a position of

```
x = Math.cos(alpha) * radius;
y = Math.sin(alpha) * radius;
```

Where each slice of the wheel is drawn as following.

```
var slice = {startAngle: deg2rad(deg), stopAngle: deg2rad(deg+sliceDeg), deg: deg};
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, width/2, slice.startAngle, slice.stopAngle);
```

Where the slices are drawn as following

```
function drawAll(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, width); //Clear the canvas
  for(var i=0; i < locations.length; i++){ 
    drawSlice(deg, color[i]);
    deg += sliceDeg;
  }
}
```

So what I am basically trying to understand is how I am to check whether in which of the slices bounds the ball is when it stops. My thesis is that I have to check it as following.

If the angle of the ball(alpha) is within the angle created by slices[i].startAngle and -||-.stopAngle. Get that slice and alert this item. Where I am lost is basically when I am to compare the radians that the slice is represented with the x and y position that the ball is represented with. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Math.atan2(y, x)` to convert cartesian coordinates back into radians.

For instance, `Math.atan2(1, 1)` yields `0.7853981633974483`, which is 45 degrees.

You may need to fiddle with the signs of `y` and `x`, if the results seem wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The ball angle is given by

```
atan2(Y - Cx, X - Cy)
```

in radians. If the angle is negative, add `2π` to be in range `[0, 2π)`.

Then `floor(Angle / sliceRad)` tells you the slice index.

Comment: So i have not quite gotten it to work to be honest with you. See jsFiddle as following. Can you see where i went wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/gwzmn7m6/#&togetherjs=EzdzOeAGcQ

Comment: @Albinwärme: you didn't say that the roulette wasn't seen from the top.

Comment: Well i mean the canvas is in a 1:1 ratio but the css that i have applied to it makes the canvas height < width to make for a better feeling. Does that change alot in how we account for the winner?

Comment: @Albinwärme: stretching does not preserve angles.

Comment: Update: I have gotten it to work with the tips that you provided. However it only do works when the Wheel is not spinning. See jsFiddle as linked. When you uncomment the movement of the wheel (at line 130) you will find that it will start giving wrong results again. What could that be dependant on. I have no idea personally

Comment: "What could that be dependant on": mh, on the spinning, maybe... Adjust for the rotating angle origin.

Comment: Am I to subtract the orgin angle from the now beeing angle?

Comment: @Albinwärme: yep. Then make sure to use the `floor` function.